# Unit testing using Nunit gives an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit, asp.net-web-api2

I just started with unit testing using Nunit with my WebApi project.

I've developed one test case for my controller:

```
private readonly INewsBusinessLogic _newsBusinessLogic;

[Test] 
public async Task GetAllNews()
{
   // Arrange
   var controller = new NewsController(_newsBusinessLogic);

   controller.Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
   controller.Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();

    // Act
    var actionResult = await controller.Get(); 

   //assert
   Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
}
```

Api controller:

```
public class NewsController : ApiController 
{  
    private readonly INewsBusinessLogic _newsBusinessLogic;

    public NewsController(INewsBusinessLogic newsBusinessLogic)
    {
        _newsBusinessLogic = newsBusinessLogic;
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
       return Ok(await _newsBusinessLogic.GetNewsUpdates());
    }
}
```

When I debug my test it gives me an error of `NullReferenceException` on *Act* , well I know very well that [What is a NullReferenceException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). But cannot figure it out, why this is occurred and how to solve it.

Side Note: I'm not using any ORM.

Comment: well for one, you are passing in a `null` variable into `NewsController` constructor as you have not shown in your example where a value is assigned to `_newsBusinessLogic`

Comment: You misunderstand. In the test you have not assigned a value to variable, hence why it is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well for one, you are passing in a `null` variable into `NewsController` constructor as you have not shown in your example where a value is assigned to `_newsBusinessLogic`

Here is an example using [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) of how to mock the controller's dependency

```
[Test] 
public async Task GetAllNews()
{
   // Arrange
   var newsBusinessLogicMock = new Mock<INewsBusinessLogic>();
   newsBusinessLogicMock
      .Setup(m => m.GetNewsUpdates())
      .ReturnsAsync("{your desired return here}");

   var controller = new NewsController(newsBusinessLogicMock.Object);

   controller.Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
   controller.Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();

    // Act
    var actionResult = await controller.Get(); 

   //assert
   Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, error gone, but  `actionResult` getting null result, can you please tell me the possible cause.

Comment: What did you set for `ReturnsAsync` in the test arrange?

Comment: I've set `List<NewsUpdatesSharedModel>` like `.ReturnsAsync(new List<NewsUpdatesSharedModel>());`

Comment: Just to confirm. Is `GetNewsUpdates` an async method?

Comment: Yes, it is. Let me explain a bit more, when i debug its reach to my controller method, but does not reach to the my BL and DAL

Comment: Thats because the test is mocking the interface. It will not hit your actual BL and DAL. it a mock. a fake of the intended implementation of the interface. If the goal is to call actual implementations then this unit test turns into an integration test.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarification, so now i need to create a separate tests for BL and DAL